# Areca Palm Leaf Disintegrating-Help

Tags: identification, diagnosis, indoors, palm, areca-palm

Can anyone help me understand what is causing the leaf to disintegrate. I repotted and checked for insects/bugs too.

Thank you!
[image: arecapalmleaf]